# Webcam from Windows to Ubuntu via XRDP

Tags: ubuntu, camera, xrdp

Situation:

1. Windows 10 machine with integrated webcam and external USB webcam.
2. Ubuntu 20.04 desktop
3. Connection via xRDP from Windows to Ubuntu (with both webcams being selected under the "local resources" tab > "Video capture devices").

The connection to the remote Ubuntu host works fine. However, the local webcams are not available in ubuntu (I tried it with "cheese").

Any ideas how to passthrough the local (Windows) webcam to the remote (Ubuntu) session?